# How to use Docker Remote API from a linux container to it's Windows host

Tags: docker

I'm trying to list containers running on my windows host (my dev laptop) from within a running linux container. However, I'm unable to get the network call to succeed. I've opened up what I believe the appropriate port to be (2376) though I haven't been able to find a ton of information on how to find the actual remote api url.

When I run the command I get `No such device or address`. It's worth pointing out that I'm using Docker Engine, not Docker Machine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Doesn't docker run inside a VM on Windows? Use `docker-machine env` on Windows to get the best configuration.

Comment: @kichik Hrm I actually get the following when I run that: `Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists`

Comment: You might have named it something else. Use `docker-machine ls` to find the real name.

Comment: I get zero results when I do `docker-machine ls`. I updated my question to state that I'm using Docker Engine.

Comment: What's the exact command you run that fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. I simply needed to mount the following volume:

"/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"